# Order type of monotone functions on $\Bbb N$ up to affine conjugation

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, order-theory

Let's introduce order on non-strictly monotone functions $\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that $f \leq g$ if $f(n) \leq Cg(Cn + C) + C$ and, of course, identify such $f, g$ if $f \leq g \leq f$. (Note absence of linear term in this definition which is usually present in geometric group theory texts; we just conjugate by affine maps of domain and target.)

1. Can we somehow describe the order type of $\{f: f \leq 2^n\}$? (i. e. things that look like growth functions of discrete metric spaces with somewhat bounded geometry) Does its sup-min lattice admit a homomorphism to some not too big totally ordered set? (I'd like to imagine this lattice as a graph with nondiscrete vertex set lying on a "big plane" with horisontal sections consisiting of antichans and vertical direction representing *essential* growth hierarchy; maybe/probably this intuition is terminally unusable)
2. Let's recall that functions greater than $2^n$ exist, but forget something else. What about class of functions realised by Dehn functions? Dehn functions of f. p. groups? Cheeger functions of quasihomogeneous discrete metric space?
3. Can we find the "finest" (or, better, "fine enough and naturally describable in non-circular and constructive fashion") equivalence relation on functions less than $2^n$ such that order type becomes describable in "finite terms"? (take those finite terms ad libitum)

I'm sorry for typical "ten questions in one" approach, but I feel that satisfactory answer will cover all or most of that stuff.

Comment: Question 1 is related to **cardinal characteristics of the continuum**. In particular, note that any countable set of functions is dominated by a single function, which prevents this partial order from "fitting" into any picture modeled by $\mathbb{R}$ (since the latter is second-countable).

Comment: What's a QI class?

Comment: Also, what is an $\mathbb R$-graph, and what is its height function?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I hope that after last edit question became more clear.

Comment: The linear term in $\le$ (which you should rather denote $\preceq$, $\le$ being the ordinary ordering) is present in geometric group theory only when dealing with Dehn function, not in the more frequent case of dealing with the growth.